# Problem teaching my one-year-old Rottweiler how to "drop it"

Tags: dogs, training

Even after several months I seem to be having a problem teaching my one-year-old Rottweiler how to "drop it", basically try to get her to drop anything that she shouldn't have.

Our dog trainer suggests that whenever we play tug-of-war that we must win every single time. Somehow this philosophy seems wrong to me not to mention the fact that we haven't made any progress.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31646/how-can-i-get-my-dog-to-drop-the-ball-after-playing

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] to see how this site works, it only takes a minute. Are you trying to teach her to actually **drop** whatever she has in her mouth on command without you touching the object or to **let go** of a tug toy you*re currently holding? You can [edit] your question any time to add more details. -- As to the question of who should win the game, please see [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1001/12501) for detailed answers.